# rsyslog - how to forward specific log files to different destinations

Tags: regex, linux, rsyslog

I have a rsyslog server and several hundred Linux, Windows, ESX and F5 hosts that will be sending syslog messages to it. Is there any way to capture a specific character in the hostname from each message and based on what that character is forward the message to the appropriate directory?

For example, for messages from adm01lt, I want to capture the fifth character. The L is for Linux and I have a directory named /var/log/linux where I want subdirectories for each host created dynamically as the logs come in.

Another example, for messages from adm21wp, I want to capture the fifth character. The W is for Windows and I have a directory named /var/log/windows where I want subdirectories for each host created dynamically as the logs come in.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would say use `Rsyslog` which has pretty nice filter capability and you can write your regex to filter specific keywords.